# What do the sink and source keywords mean in pulseaudio?

Tags: pulseaudio

I am reading about pulseaudio, how it works and how I can configure it. I am encountering two keywords a lot: ***SINK***, ***SOURCE.***
At first I thought ***SINK*** meant ***OUTPUT*** and ***SOURCE*** meant ***INPUT***, but it seems that this is not the case.

Could someone explain what ***SINK*** and ***SOURCE*** mean in simple English?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

As per the [project description](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/About/):

> PulseAudio clients can send audio to "sinks" and receive audio from "sources".

So sinks are outputs (audio goes there), sources are inputs (audio comes from there).

Comment: Audio is output there rather than goes there a little more intuitive.

Comment: PulseAudio also has something called *source output* (e.g. `pacmd list-source-outputs`) – what on earth is that supposed to mean?

Comment: Perhaps think of it this way: *sink* and *source* refer to flow of audio data between PulseAudio and the outside world, while *input* and *output* refer to flow of audio data between PulseAudio and *other programs*.

Answer (score 15):

Sink =  speakers,  headphones

Source =  microphone

Answer (score 7):

I can't comment to Mikko because I'm new so I make this message.
As said sinks are outputs, sources are inputs, ok, but then I wondered as Mikko does about what sink-input and source-output mean, so I have done some experiment with pactl:

1. `pactl list sinks` -> I see my realtek (alc892) and nvidia audio, ok these are my sinks fair enough.
2. `pactl list sources` -> there I have seen my mic, good, but also monitoring to previous sinks, fair enough since they are like microphones to my outputs.
3. `pactl list sink-inputs` with no apps running-> nothing.
4. `pactl list source-output` with no apps running -> nothing.
5. I have opened youtube video on firefox and it appeared as a `sink-input`! So I think it means that it is an **input** to a sink hence **sink-input**.
6. I thought that OBS would have helped with `source-outputs` and I was right. I'm recording my mic and desktop audio, they appearead as `source-outputs`, the audio captured is the **output** from some source hence **source-output**.

Comment: say `source-outputs` (mind the **s** at the end).

stackexchange unfortunately does not allow me such a small edit (less than 6 characters)

Answer (score 5):

Here's a summary of all the PulseAudio specific terms (note that the words that PulseAudio uses do not match the typical use of that word):

- `input`: digital audio stream from an application to PulseAudio (e.g. audio from Youtube video playing in your web browser). Note that this has nothing to do with any physical connector that your system has.
- `output`: digital audio stream from PulseAudio to application (e.g. recorded microphone audio to be sent to video conference by your browser). Note that this has nothing to do with any physical connector that your system has.
- `source`: device that can emit digital audio stream to PulseAudio (typically microphone, line input, HDMI capture card or something similar; may or may not be backed by actual audio hardware but PulseAudio will treat it as if it was real hardware)
- `sink`: device that can output digital audio stream from PulseAudio (typically speaker signal, headphone output, HDMI output, line out; may or may not be backed by actual audio hardware but PulseAudio will treat it as if it was real hardware)

PulseAudio will then create combinations of these. For example, `pacmd list-source-outputs` will list digital streams from some `source` to some `output`, basically the *connections* between `source` devices (hardware) and software `output`s (applications).

If no application is currently taking digital streams, there are no connections even though applications that support PulseAudio are running and hardware that's able to generate audio streams are available (that is, connection exists only when application actively captures audio). I personally think that it would make more sense to call these as `recording-streams` or something like that but PulseAudio authors call these `source-outputs` instead.

It may help to think PulseAudio as a virtual mixing desk that has applications (`input` and `output`) and hardware (`source` and `sink`) connected to it and it will route streams/connections between different things.