# What is the concept of source in pulseaudio?

Tags: pulseaudio

The classical concept on sink and source in pulseaudio:
[concept on sink and source](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/260981/what-do-the-sink-and-source-keywords-mean-in-pulseaudio)

```
PulseAudio clients can send audio to "sinks" and receive audio from "sources".
So sinks are outputs (audio goes there), sources are inputs (audio comes from there).
```

Show all `sources` in my pc:

```
pactl list sources short
0   alsa_output.default.monitor module-alsa-sink.c  s32le 2ch 48000Hz   SUSPENDED
1   null.monitor    module-null-sink.c  s16le 2ch 44100Hz   SUSPENDED
2   fifo_output.monitor module-pipe-sink.c  s16le 2ch 44100Hz   SUSPENDED
3   alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo.monitor  module-alsa-card.c  s16le 2ch 44100Hz   SUSPENDED
4   alsa_input.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo   module-alsa-card.c  s16le 2ch 44100Hz   SUSPENDED
```

The 1th,2th,3th items all contain a `output` keyword here,why it belongs to `source` instead of `sink`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those are source *monitors*, *i.e.* they are sources which reflect whatever is sent to the corresponding sink.

For example, `alsa_output.default.monitor` allows you to record everything sent to the default ALSA output.